# Vanilla Javascript - Cannot GET/route - ERROR

Tags: javascript, error-handling, routes, react-router, typescript

I am having problem in my routing.I used Vanilla javascript in routing and it worked but when I go from ***http://127.0.0.1:5500/*** to ***http://127.0.0.1:5500/about*** and then refresh about page it says **Cannot GET/about**

My javascript code - router.js file

> ```
> const rootDiv = document.getElementById("root");
>
> let home = "";
> let about = "";
> let contact = "";
> let profile = "";
>
> /**
>  * @param {String} page
>  * @returns {String}
>  */
>
> const loadPage = async (page) => {
>   const response = await fetch(page);
>   const resHtml = await response.text();
>   return resHtml;
> };
>
> const loadAllPages = async () => {
>   home = await loadPage("home.html");
>   about = await loadPage("about.html");
>   contact = await loadPage("contact.html");
>   profile = await loadPage("profile.html");
> };
>
> const main = async () => {
>   await loadAllPages();
>   rootDiv.innerHTML = home;
>   routes = {
>     "/": home,
>     "/contact": contact,
>     "/about": about,
>     "/profile": profile,
>   };
> };
>
> main();
>
> /**
>  * @param {String} pathname
>  */
> const onNavigate = (pathname) => {
>   window.history.pushState({}, pathname, window.location.origin + pathname);
>   rootDiv.innerHTML = routes[pathname];
> };
>
> window.onpopstate = () => {
>   rootDiv.innerHTML = routes[window.location.pathname];
> };
> ```

Why I am getting this error??Can anyone please get me out of this.
All HTML files are in same directory.
Any help here would be very appreciated!!
Thanks!!

Comment: If you're on `http://127.0.0.1:5500/about` and you refresh, the code will run `await loadPage("home.html");` but since it's relative path, it'd try getting `http://127.0.0.1:5500/about/home.html` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Nope @VLAZ , when I reload the page it's actualy on [http://127.0.0.1:5500/about](http://127.0.0.1:5500/about). I created `PTR.js` when I `console.log` the refreshing url its `"http://127.0.0.15500" + window.location.pathname`.